# php image upload not working Error:

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to upload an image to the folder `/images` with php

this is my code:

my html

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post">
New image: <input type="file" name="newimage">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

my php (upload.php)

```
if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['newimage']['tmp_name'], "images/newimage.png"))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($db));
}
```

It just returns `Error:`   nothing else..

by the way, my image folder has the rights 777

Comment: Quick note: Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `form` element.

Comment: Try `var_dump($_FILES)` and see what you get on form submission.

Comment: sorry my bad, works now.. thank you! please make an answer to that so i can accept it (enctype="multipart/form-data")

Comment: Why would you use `mysqli_error` on a file move?

Comment: I would because i have no idea what i am doing as a beginner :D

Comment: No point in displaying a database error when no database interaction is involved :)

Comment: That makes sense.. lol thanks :) still learning..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form element.

[Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)